# Backbone using fetch with data and remove: false

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The docs are unclear and I've been unable to find the answer myself, I am wondering if using data parameters in a backbone.js fetch() overrides also having a remove: false.  I have some of the collection bootstrapped on initial load but for a certain page I need to fetch a subset of the collection, and not overwrite the models that already exist in the collection here is the gist of it:

```
    this.fetch({
        data: {
            model: {user_id: user.get('id'), is_finished: 't'}
        },
        remove: false,
        success: function(collection, response, options) {
            console.log(collection);
            console.log(options);
        },
        error: function(collection, response, options) {
            //oh noes
        }
    });
```

The options in the console shows all the previous models that have been removed and only the models that match the data remain in the collection upon success.  To me it seems like the remove: false is just getting ignored, am I crazy?  When I tested the same fetch without the data parameter and the remove: false functions properly.

Comment: You can pass a function to the remove option, so you can do custom logic with your data: remove: function() { ... }

Comment: There's no way using `data` would override the `remove` flag. Are you using Backbone 1.0?

Comment: omg didn't even think to check that I'm using the backbone-on-rails gem, had version 0.9.9.0 just upgraded to 1.0 and it works.  Answer it so I can accept! And thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to Backbone 1.0 the default behavior of the `fetch` method is to reset your collection. Upgrade to Backbone 1.0 to update by default.